# Keep a relative position using quaternion orientation

Tags: math, quaternions

Let's say I have an object (A) with a position stored as a 3-number vector, and an orientation stored as a quaternion.

I have a second object (B) with the same information.

Object B is, for whatever reason, suddenly welded to object A. It is now stuck, and should perfectly move around relative to object A.

If object B is stuck to a corner of object A, and object A rotates, object B should be in the same relative position and orientation in that same corner as it was before.

To illustrate what I'm asking, it should look something like this:

[image]

So far I've managed to take object B's position and transform it by the inverse of the object A's position/orientation, storing an accurate relative position - then when object A rotates, I simply transform the relative position by object A's position/orientation, and teleport object B to that position. This keeps the object B on the corner of A, as expected... however, this does not *rotate* object B to match object A... how should I go about tracking the relative orientation, using quaternions or matrices (Euler angles are a worst case scenario only, as they are expensive to calculate).

EDIT: I only have a quaternion from before and a quaternion from after. No details on the rotation itself.

In addition, the rotation is arbitrary and free, it could be about any axis or multiple axes at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most perfect answer has come to me after a lot of googling and experimentation: Disregard original ideas, acquire matrices!

`B.Matrix * Invert(A.Matrix)` is stored as a `relative` marker, And then to restore, simply replace B's matrix with `relative * A.MATRIX`.

This perfectly adjusts both rotation and position in one all-mighty swoop.

I have no idea how to do the same with quaternions, but who cares, when we have matrices!

Comment: I was just about to answer this! And you are totally on the right track. Forget quaternions angles or positions. Understand matrices and linear transforms first. Think of a matrix as a "space" - in math it's called a "base". Transforming a vector by multiplying it with a matrix takes it into that space. And from that follows the most unintuitive thing about matrices: going to space A and from there to B is not the same as going to B and then to A.

Comment: @starmole: Saying that a basis (not "base") is the same as a space is incorrect. A basis is what generates or "spans" a space, but there can be many different bases for the same space. In the situation we're talking about here, the space is always R^3, and rotating/translating simply is a change of the coordinate system, not of the space.

Comment: To expand on why this solution works: inverting the `A.Matrix` basically transforms B to A's local coordinate system. Once this is done, we can simply transform B along with the rest of `A` by applying the `A.Matrix`.

Comment: Or in mathematical terms: `relative * A.Matrix = B.Matrix * inv(A.Matrix) * A.Matrix = B.Matrix`, so B keeps its original location and transformation in world coordinates, but is expressed in A's coordinate system.

Comment: @cfh you are right of course. english is not my native language which makes math terms a bit harder (base or basis?). But I also did not try to be precise but helpful. I thought the word space describes how 3d graphics people might think - but maybe that was wrong, because it is not the right term in math.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement the algorithm described [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/rotate/).

You need to rotate B about an arbitrary axis - the same axis that you are rotating A about. I'm assuming you have an axis that you are rotating A about.  If not, you can calculate one using the center point of A and a line parallel to the rotation normal.

Comment: It's not rotating about an axis, it's rotating freely. The only information I have is the before-quaternion and the after-quaternion.

Comment: Its rotating about some axis, even if its the one that passes through A.  Every rotation has an axis.

Comment: It could rotate about multiple axes at once though.

Comment: True.  Then you would need to apply those rotations as separate operations.  Just to be clear though, when I say axis, I don't mean the X, Y, Z axes - I mean a line that is the axis of the rotation.

Comment: I can't do that though. I don't control the system that is rotating things, I am simply given the object's position/orientation at any given point in time and need to keep an object stuck on accurately. (For clarity: I'm sticking a non-physics object to a physics object in a physics engine. The physics engine does not provide a 'rotation event' or anything, I simply have to react every update step)

Comment: You can calculate the rotation between the A position and orientation before and after.  Then apply the same rotation to B (but use the same axis).

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable... how would I do that? Unlike Euler Angles, I can't simply subtract one quaternion from another or anything easy like that.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva: Every rotation can be written as a rotation around a single axis. If you concatenate several rotations, the end result is again a rotation (but with a different axis).